# Qt5PrintSupportd.dll is missing

Tags: c++, qt

I searched about that problem everywhere, i really don t know what to do.I created a notepad app, in compiler everything went fine but when i m running it external it gives me that error : The program can t start because QT5PrintSupportd.dll is missing from your computer

Edit: Everything works fine now thanks a lot guys.

Comment: [here](https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/qt5printsupport_dll.html), I think you will understand what file is missing and how to fix it. In  your System `.dll` file is corrupted

Comment: i should add this in system32?

Comment: you need to download it and then install.

Comment: use windeployqt: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example my Qt install is inside : **C:\Qt\Qt5.11.1\5.11.1\msvc2015_64\bin**
Qt5PrintSupportd.dll is inside the bin folder. If you can't find the dll reinstalled Qt.

After copy this dll near to the .exe or add to system32.

For window, may be you need to add the plugin folder printsupport near to the .exe file.
You can find this folder in **C:\Qtpath\plugins\printsupport**

```
----   
    | app.exe  
    | printsupport\windowsprintersupportd.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

The Qt command ['windeployqt'](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) is the proper way to copy all of the needed Qt stuff to your application's directory.

Answer (score 0):

PrintSupport is a standard module of Qt 5, so you should have it within your Qt's installation dir: `<qt_dir>\bin\Qt5PrintSupport[d].dll`.

Notice the `d` suffix in the filename, it indicates it is the debug version. `Qt5PrintSupport.dll` is for release, `Qt5PrintSupportd.dll` is for debug.

Now, you have to copy that DLL from your Qt's installation and paste it in the same directory as of your executable (probably you've also copied other Qt DLLs there). Again, be aware of the difference between release and debug DLLs.

*Note: I would not copy it to any directory in the path but to your executable's directory. In this way you avoid future conflicts if you upgrade your Qt version.*